# Skipping Chapter numbering but getting the Chapter layout

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, parts

I'd like to set up the structure of my report as follows.

Different chapters should have a nice big heading, like the one of the Chapter environment, and should be separated in the table of contents as well. Each chapter can then contain some sections and subsections.

My only problem with this environment is the numbering: numbering of sections should proceed unaltered by the fact that we are passing from one chapter to another. In other words there should be no counter for chapters in the total numbering.

How it is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}                 
\geometry{letterpaper}                  
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Section1}
\section{section2}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{section3}
\section{section4}

\end{document}
```

Basically I'd like the discrete numbering features of the part environment, but the graphical layout of the chapter env.

Comment: Do you just want `\chapter*{Chapter title}`? That will not number the chapters at all. You can then add them to the table of contents manually. But I'm not very clear whether you want this or want numbered chapters but without resetting the section counters? By the way, your code does not compile without errors here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answering, I've removed commands which caused errors and packages which were extraneous to the issue.

If you just don't want the chapters numbered at all, but you do want them to show up in the contents, something like this might be suitable:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{remreset}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand \thesection {\@arabic\c@section}
  \@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{First chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{First chapter}
\section{Section1}
\section{section2}

\chapter*{Second chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Second chapter}
\section{section3}
\section{section4}

\end{document}
```

[image: Unnumbered chapters]

[image: Chapters without numbers]

If you want the chapters numbered, this might work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{remreset}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand \thesection {\@arabic\c@section}
  \@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Section1}
\section{section2}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{section3}
\section{section4}

\end{document}
```

[image: Numbered chapters]

[image: Chapters with numbers]

Comment: That is perfect.

Comment: @Brightsun In that case, upvote and accept it. :-)

Comment: It appears the page ha not registered my upvote earlier, my bad I didn't check.

Comment: @Brightsun Glad it helped. Just out of interest, which solution did you need?

Comment: @cfr The first one, even though I have to admit that I don't quite understand what's happening in your solution. I mean, what is the "makeatletter" stuff? Where do I learn how to use those commands and so forth?

Comment: @Brightsun The `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is needed because the commands I use there include the `@` symbol. Usually, this is only allowed in package and class files - not in documents themselves. Surrounding the commands with `\makeatletter...\makeatother` allows me to use `@` in command names in the preamble. The first command there is modified from the command I found in `report.cls`. The second is provided by the `remreset` package. I found this by searching this site for `remreset` as I remembered seeing it used somewhere.