# Surpress chapter-numbering in table of contents and hyperlinks

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, numbering, chapters, report

I am writing a solutions manual companion to some lecture notes. I want the numbering of exercises, solutions, and chapter to align. Thus I want the structure of the document to be something like

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\chapter*{Exercises}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Exercises}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand*{\theHsection}{exercises.\the\value{section}}
    \section{Laplace transform (chapter 1 in the lecture notes)}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection{}
    \section{Matrix algebra (chapter 2 in the lecture notes)}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection{}
\chapter*{Solutions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Solutions}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand*{\theHsection}{solutions.\the\value{section}}
    \section{Laplace transform (chapter 1 in the lecture notes)}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection{}
    \section{Matrix algebra (chapter 2 in the lecture notes)}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection{}
\end{document}
```

...using the hack on hyperref from here: [Reset section numbering between unnumbered chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71162/reset-section-numbering-between-unnumbered-chapters)

[image]

There is one issue with this. I get the chapter level numbering displayed! E.g. subsection 0.2.1 for exercise/solution 2.1

How do I get rid of that numbering?

Comment: Imho it would make more sense to use article class and \part instead of \chapter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes indeed. I didnt know that was possible. I think I get it all to work correctly by doing the replacements of article instead of report, and then changing all "chapter" to "part". And that is it.... it seems. Any pitfalls to consider? Otherwise Im happy to use that as an answer, if you propose it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the preamble did the trick for me :

Taken from [Skipping Chapter numbering but getting the Chapter layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170023/skipping-chapter-numbering-but-getting-the-chapter-layout)

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand \thesection {\@arabic\c@section}
  \@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

[image]